# Why can two different enum enumeration-constants have the same integer value?

Tags: c, enums

I know that if I defined an enum weekday like this:

```
enum weekday {
    MON,
    TUE,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRI,
};
```

Then, MON would internally equal to 0, by default, and TUE to 1, WED to 2...

But if I define it this way:

```
enum weekday {
    MON,
    TUE = 0,
    WED,
    THU,
    FRI,
};
```

Then both `MON` and `TUE` would get the value of 0.

How would a system differentiate MON and TUE internally? I mean, if I declare something like this:

```
enum weekday today = 0;
```

Then is today `MON` or `TUE`? Or, philosophically speaking, both?

Comment: @quasiverse - I did, `MON` and `TUE` are both `0`. +1, I didn't know that.

Comment: The `enum` constants are `int`s. They're just hopefully meaningful names for some integer constants. So what's the deal if you can refer to the same thing with two names?

Comment: There's no philosophy, just logic: `today == MON == TUE == 0`.

Comment: A "is it legal" version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5561142/duplicate-enum-values-in-c/30916470#30916470

Comment: it's basically an alternative to constexpr for systems that don't support constexpr. except the constexpr ints are coupled

Answer (score 90):

C enums are "really" integers -- not just because they happen to be implemented that way, but because the standard *defines* enum types to have integer values. So the value of `today` is "really" 0. All that has happened is that you've created two different names for the value 0.

I suppose then that the answer to "is today MON or TUE" is "yes" ;-)

The language doesn't stop you because occasionally it's useful for an enum to have multiple names for the same value. For example:

```
enum compression_method {
    COMP_NONE = 0,
    COMP_LOW = 1,
    COMP_HIGH = 2,
    COMP_BEST = 2,
    COMP_FASTEST = 0,
};
```

Comment: Hahahahha, +1 for `I suppose then that the answer to "is today MON or TUE" is "yes" ;-)` :D

Comment: A better solution here is to have `COMP_FASTEST = COMP_NONE`, in my opinion.

Comment: even if MON and TUE were different, the answer to "is today MON or TUE" can still be "yes", given the computer "OR" operation. I think you were searching for "is today MON and TUE"

Answer (score 26):

**Why can two different enumeration-constants have the same integer value?**

Because it is explicitly allowed by the [N1265 C99 standard draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) at 6.7.2.2/3 "Enumeration specifiers":

> The use of enumerators with `=` may produce enumeration constants with values that duplicate other values in the same enumeration.

**How would a system differentiate MON and TUE internally?**

I think it is impossible because they are compile time constants (6.6/6 "Constant expressions"). As a consequence they:

- cannot be modified to make them differ after compilation
- have no address to tell them apart: [Memory location of enum value in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206579/memory-location-of-enum-value-in-c)

  Compile time constants don't need any address because addresses are useless for things which you cannot modify.

GCC simply replaces the usage of enum members with immediate values in assembly at compile time. Consider:

```
#include <stdio.h>

enum E {
    E0 = 0x1234,
    E1 = 0x1234
};
int i = 0x5678;

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", E0);
    printf("%d\n", E1);
    printf("%d\n", i);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile and decompile with GCC 4.8 x86_64:

```
gcc -c -g -O0 -std=c89 main.c
objdump -Sr main.o
```

The output contains:

```
    printf("%d\n", E0);
   4:       be 34 12 00 00          mov    $0x1234,%esi
  ...
    printf("%d\n", E1);
  18:       be 34 12 00 00          mov    $0x1234,%esi
  ...
    printf("%d\n", i);
  2c:       8b 05 00 00 00 00       mov    0x0(%rip),%eax        # 32 <main+0x32>
                    2e: R_X86_64_PC32       i-0x4
  32:       89 c6                   mov    %eax,%esi
```

So we see that:

- the enum members are used as immediates `$0x1234`, so it is impossible to know where they came from
- the variable `i` however comes from memory `0x0(%rip)` (to be relocated), so two variables could be differentiated by address

Answer (score 14):

Just to complement on other answers, I'll give you a practical example of how using the same value for different enumerations on a given `enum` is widely useful:

```
enum slots_t {
    SLOT_FIRST = 0,
    SLOT_LEFTARM = SLOT_FIRST,
    SLOT_RIGHTARM = 1,
    SLOT_TORSO = 2,
    SLOT_LEFTLEG = 3,
    SLOT_RIGHTLEG = 4,
    SLOT_LAST = SLOT_RIGHTLEG
};
```

Then you can do in your code:

```
for (int i = SLOT_FIRST; i <= SLOT_LAST; ++i) { }
```

Comment: I would rather define a SLOT_MAX = 4 instead of SLOTLAST = SLOT_RIGHTLEG in case some other programmer comes to the great idea to exchange the values for SLOT_LEFTLEG and SLOT_RIGHTLEG

Comment: Normally I use SLOT_MAX with not forced value to have the compiler assign last + 1.  This allow to have array defined, ex: `bool slot_valid[SLOT_MAX];`   Or looping with more traditional `i < SLOT_MAX`.

Answer (score 10):

It's as philosophical (or not) as

```
#define ZILCH 0
#define NADA  0
```

There are many uses where it makes sense to have different names result in the same number.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the enumeration constant is used to assign the value and not the actual value itself. If you assign the value 0 to today the output value will be 0.
And yes, both MON and TUE will have the value 0 and the remaining will assigned the value as WED=1 THU=2 and so on.